# Conditional based on whether or not replace occured

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I want to know whether or not a replace occurs. What I'd like to be able to do:

```
bool SomethingWasReplaced = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells.Replace What:="foo", Replacement:="bar", _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

If SomethingWasReplaced Then
...
```

My internet searches did not reveal a way to do this. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do that with just a replace (despite what it says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086%28v=office.15%29.aspx)), you'll probably have to do it with a search then a replace

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ws      As Worksheet
    Dim search  As Range
    Dim found   As Range

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set search = ws.Cells
        Set found = search.Find(What:="foo", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        Do While Not found Is Nothing
            found.replace What:="foo", replacement:="bar"
            '' you now know something was replaced here, do whatever else you need   

            Set found = search.Find(What:="foo", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, After:=found)
        Loop
    Next ws

End Sub
```

My suspicion is `.Replace()` returns true if it worked (didn't error) and not based on whether or not it actually replaced anything.

Comment: `Replace` returns a string which is the changed value. We could compare this to the original value of the cell to see if a replacement occurred. This is not necessary though because within your current code you can just check if the loop was entered, with a boolean.

Comment: It depends on which `Replace` we're talking about. If we're talking `Range.Replace()` then it returns a boolean (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086(v=office.15).aspx). If we're talking the `Replace` function then yes it does return a string (http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace.php). If the `Replace` function were used you'd have to loop through every single cell rather than doing a `Find` first which I think would be slightly less efficient. The `Replace` function could be used within the `Do While` loop in my code though with the same functionality.

Comment: Yes, sorry, F1 took me to the wrong function ;) (WorksheetFunction.Replace rather than Range.Replace).

Comment: If only that was the way it worked! This is why I prefer languages like C#, I can bend it to my will much easier ;)

Comment: Well, yes, but VBA is more capable then people give it credit for.. but we won't go off topic!